# how to remove digit grouping in Windows calculator

Tags: windows-10, calculator

How do I disable digit grouping in Windows 10 Calculator only? I have seen [how to change these settings systemwide](https://www.officetooltips.com/office/tips/how_to_change_decimal_symbol_and_digit_grouping_symbol_in_windows_10.html), however I am looking to only change this setting for Windows 10 Calculator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible at this time to change digit grouping only for the windows calculator, you need to do this system wide.

However, you could use a third party calculator like Qalculate as this has three configurable options for digit grouping.

> digit grouping, group (0* = off, 1 = standard, 2 = locale)

Source: https://qalculate.github.io/manual/qalc.html